# Firebase Data Retrieval

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for Android to make an app that involves groups
I have a list of items in my firebase that were pushed using the push method and look like this:

```
-Groups Joined:
               ~Unique Key: Group 1 Name
               ~Unique Key: Group 2 Name
```

I am trying to retrieve this list as a Java List in my android code. I need to be able to access the information in the Groups Joined node by index instead of with the Unique Key, I am using this code.

```
Query groupsJoined = myUserRef.child("Groups Joined").orderByKey();

    groupsJoined.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // do some stuff once
            groupNames = (ArrayList<String>) snapshot.getValue();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
```

The code crashes because snapshot.getValue() is returning an object of type map. I have no way to access the elements of the map because I am not storing these unique keys on the android device and I have no desire to. How can I get the data snapshot to be returned as something I can iterate through and get the group names out of without having to use the unique keys?

Comment: You can iterate through the values of a `Map` - is that not sufficient? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values().

Comment: Groups are naturally ordered by key, so the query here is not necessary. What have you tried so far? Data is pretty easy to iterate. Particularly considering that getChildren() returns Iterable. Also, you probably want child added events rather than a singleValueEvent.

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty straight forward to convert a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Try this code:

```
myUserRef.child("Groups Joined").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        // do some stuff once
        Map groupNames = snapshot.getValue();
        List groupNamesList = new ArrayList(groupNames.values());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

If the default behavior of `snapshot.getValue()` doesn't cut it, you can also [pass in a Java class](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getValue(java.lang.Class)), and the client will attempt to deseralize it into that class using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).